# Getting a Count of Users by Date

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to create a query that will return results for the number of distinct users who have accessed something by date.  Right now I have a query that will display 2 columns, the first being date and the second being user name.  It will list all the distinct users who accessed the application on a certain date but they will each have their own distinct row.  Here is the query that does that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT logdate, User AS ReportUser
FROM table          
WHERE appname='abcd1234' AND logdate >=DATE-30
```

I have tried putting COUNT() around User but it says selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.

Any idea how I can get this query to just show like row for the past 30 days and the count of distinct users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the right approach for that.

```
SELECT logdate, Count(User) AS ReportUser
FROM table          
WHERE appname='abcd1234' AND logdate >=DATE-30
GROUP BY 1
```

**Never** use `DINTINCT` in Teradata. It always slows down your query performance. Use `GROUP BY`instead.

***CORRECTION*** In Teradata 13 the optimizer is able to determines which version is more efficient, based on statistics. This can be found in the Release Summary for Teradata 13 under "Group By and DISTINCT Performance Equivalence". - http://www.info.teradata.com/edownload.cfm?itemid=083440012 (PDF)

Comment: Will that count distinct users? The original question was for distinct users

Comment: Thanks, i do have to use count(distinct user) though since the table inserts a row every time a query is run.

Comment: @RobPaller Unable to open that PDF file - "The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error.
Please contact the website administrator. "

Comment: @emaillenin - Corrected address. For some reason it requires but doesn't resolve to www.{address}

Comment: @RobPaller Thanks. Do you have experience in Bigdata & hadoop?

Comment: Guess it depends on what Big Data means to you. But I am managing a 100+ TB data warehouse currently. I'm afraid I have not worked with Hadoop at this point in time.

Comment: @RobPaller I am writing a Teradata certification this month end. I have few questions on Teradata as a career. Can we talk over email?

Comment: Sure. We can talk over email. Check my profile for my email address.

Answer (score 0):

use "GROUP BY" after WHERE clause

```
SELECT logdate, COUNT (User) AS ReportUser 
FROM table           
WHERE appname='abcd1234' AND logdate >=DATE-30 
GROUP BY logdate
```

Comment: DISTINCT is a disgrace in TERADATA

Comment: Prior to TD 13, you had to understand the nuances where DISTINCT should be used over GROUP BY. After Teradata 13 the optimizer handles it for you. See my comment above.